# Drop-downs not opening after installing chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have made a simple chrome extension which includes things like, sending requests after taking some data from the chrome. I am able to do all those things by using the chrome extension documentation. But, after some time I realized that on some of the websites, dropdowns are not opening.

I have seen the console output of the website, extension and background.js, none of them are producing any errors.

Here is the code of manifest.js

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "version": "1.1",
    "description": "Another extension",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "author": "My Name",
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "identity"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "handlers/html/popup.html",
        "default_title": "Some title",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "handlers/images/get_started16.png",
            "32": "handlers/images/get_started32.png",
            "48": "handlers/images/get_started48.png",
            "128": "handlers/images/get_started128.png"
        }
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "handlers/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
            "handlers/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "handlers/js/background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "handlers/images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "handlers/images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "handlers/images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "handlers/images/get_started128.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "handlers/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
                "handlers/js/bootstrap.min.js",
                "contentscript.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You need to clarify what those "drop-downs" are and how you create them, optionally show the relevant code.

Comment: I am not creating them... For example, when I open the GitLab website with the given chrome extension, I am not able to open the dropdowns of projects.

Comment: Sounds like your contentscript.js breaks things.

Comment: Found it! It was due to bootstrap and some other random things in the `content_scripts`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by removing bootstrap.min.js from the `content_script` in the manifest file.